# Stable Acute Triangles in a Grid

Tags: co.combinatorics, ramsey-theory

The following combinatorial question came up while trying to prove a lemma for my research. Let $[N]$ denote the $N\times N$ grid inside the integer lattice $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}.$ The square corresponding to $(z_1,z_2)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is $[z_1-\frac{1}{2},z_1+\frac{1}{2}]\times [z_2-\frac{1}{2},z_2+\frac{1}{2}]\subset\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}.$ If $x\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z},$ denote the corresponding square by $S(x).$

**Definition**
An *acute three-tuple* $\left\{x_1,x_2,x_3\right\}$ is a collection of three elements $x_i\in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ so that for every choice of $y_1\in S(x_1),$ $y_2\in S(x_2),$ and $y_3\in S(x_3),$  the triangle with vertices $y_1, y_2,$ and $y_3$ is acute.

Let $\lambda(N)$ be the size of the largest subset of $[N]$ with no acute three-tuple.

**Question**
Is $\lambda(N) = O(N^{1+\epsilon})$ for all $\epsilon>0$?

I have shown that $\lambda(N) = O(N^{1.5}),$ but the argument is not easily strengthenable.

I initially posted this on stackexchange, and did not get an answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2356166/stable-acute-triangles-in-a-grid

Comment: I wonder if there might be ideas that help in this paper: Bevan, David. "Sets of points determining only acute angles and some related colouring problems." *The Electronic Journal of Combinatorics* 13.1 (2006): R12. [PDF download](http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/EJC/Volume_13/PDF/v13i1r12.pdf).

Comment: Do you have examples where the number of points grows faster than $N$?